# Additional Workflow Data in Project Server Workflow empty

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow, ms-project-server-2013

I am trying to build a Project Server workflow using SharePoint Designer 2013.

The *workflow itself is working*.  It can create a task in the Project Server task list and approving it progresses the workflow.

However, if you click ***"Additional Workflow Data" the history is always empty***.  I have been able to create a custom event to log in the history via designer, but I am looking for the true history of the workflow.  In 2010, the history would show it entering each stage and other logging data.  My 2013 workflow history shows nothing.

I have verified the account has permissions to write to the list. I have checked the IIS logs to see the workflows are running. I have checked the project server permissions and groups for the workflow proxy account.  I have ensured "Workflows can use app permissions" is activated for the PWA collection.  I have also tried "Copy-SPActivitesToWorkflowService" cmd to see if it needed to installation needed to be repaired.  I have restarted the workflows, republished, bounced the boxes, but still not workflow history!!

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue or have other suggestions on where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sticking point comes from a differences in versions.

In Project Server 2010, the workflows showed default actions and processes.  In 2013, you cannot see all the various behind-the-scenes actions.

Any actions which you want to be able to trace, for example, when the project entered the stage, must be added into the custom workflow manually.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an 'Action' within the Workflow called 'Log to History List' and enter what you want the log to say at the point where you have added the Action.